# Why does dragging and dropping on the Unity launcher sometimes moves the icon and sometimes slides all icons?

Tags: unity, launcher

I am trying to rearrange the icons on my Unity launcher. Sometimes I can just drag and drop an icon without difficulty. But other times when I attempt to drag an icon all icons on the launcher slide together. Why is that? What can I do to make sure my dragging and dropping performs one of these actions or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click and move quickly you drag all the icons.

If you click, wait and move you move a single icon.

Comment: Thanks, that works! It's worth adding that @ByteCommander's answer - moving an icon first horizontally and then vertically - also works.

Answer (score 1):

My observation is that:

- You slide all icons up and down if you click and hold an icon and then move the mouse vertically.
- You can move one single icon inside the launcher by clicking and holding it and then first moving a bit horizontally to free it. After that you can drag it wherever you want.

I am currently on XFCE so I can't check, but this is how I remember it from Unity.

Comment: Thanks, @ByteCommander! I've accepted @mark rigby's answer (to wait before moving) as it was here first and it works, but added a reference to your answer which is good too.

Comment: @Tom No problem! :-) It's your choice which answer you like best, but I'm happy that mine works too (in this case I wasn't really sure because I used Unity a while ago) and you also like it.